# Can we automate Schedular application testcases in Selenium?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I have a scheduler application (java springboot) which I have to run and which is placed in unix NAS storage drive. its job is to schedule producer, consumer.

For this we have around 30 testcases prepared if any changes made in scheduler application we have to run the 30 old tc and create new tc according to the changes.
All the test cases involve running schedular app in unix server and it does not have an UI. after running schedular app you can verify in the terminal logs or in db where it will update the status of the jobs, based on that we can decide whether tc is passed or failed

can we automate this testcases? Selenium is browser based tool or can automate these tc in selenium.

you can't connect to unix server to run schedular app from windows, you have to create jar, war and place it in unix server because of security compliance, that's the only option.